# Get the links to the status updates on Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: facebook, twitter, links, status

I want to give a link to a status update of me to others. Is there any way to get that link to each status update on Facebook and Twitter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a direct link to a Status Update or a Tweet you click the time of the Status Update or Tweet was posted.

This opens the Status Update or Tweet on its own.  You can then use this URL as a direct link that particular Status Update or Tweet.

**Facebook**

[image: Facebook - Direct Link to Status Update]

**Twitter**
[image: Twitter - Direct Link to Tweet]